# django - can't view data on django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

Here are the models I am working with:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    user_pass = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.full_name

class CustomerDetail(models.Model):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex = r'^\d{10}$', message = "Invalid format! E.g. 4088385778")
    date_regex = RegexValidator(regex = r'^(\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})$', message = "Invalid format! E.g. 05/16/91")

    customer = models.OneToOneField(
        Customer,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(validators = [date_regex], max_length = 10, blank = True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    home_phone = models.CharField(validators = [phone_regex], max_length = 10, blank = True)
    work_phone = models.CharField(validators = [phone_regex], max_length = 10, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.customer.full_name
```

Here is the `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import CustomerDetail

class CustomerDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerDetail
        fields = ['address', 'date_of_birth', 'company', 'home_phone', 'work_phone',]
```

I have a view in my application (after user is logged in) called `create_profile` that asks the user for additional details and I used ModelForm instance to implement it. Here is the snippet from `views.py`:

```
def create_profile(request):
if request.POST:
    form = CustomerDetailForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        address = form.cleaned_data['address']
        date_of_birth = form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        company = form.cleaned_data['company']
        home_phone = form.cleaned_data['home_phone']
        work_phone = form.cleaned_data['work_phone']

        profdata = CustomerDetail(address = address, date_of_birth = date_of_birth, company = company, home_phone = home_phone, work_phone = work_phone)
        profdata.save()

        return render(request, 'newuser/profile_created.html', {form: form})
else:
    return redirect(create_profile)
```

When I fill the form on the corresponding template html and hit Submit, it shows me the successive page, but when I check the CustomerDetail entries on the admin page, I see a '-' in place of an actual record. Where am I going wrong here? Does it have to do with overriding the clean() method? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override `cleaned_data` in your case. Because you already using `ModelForm` which create `CustomerDetail` instance after `save` method called.
View might look like this:

```
def create_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerDetailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'newuser/profile_created.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = CustomerDetailForm()
    return render(request, 'path_to_create_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

[check the docs about forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view)

Comment: Can you explain what is happening in the else part here?

Comment: @KrithikaRaghavendran in the else form is empty for `GET` response

Comment: `form.save()` isn't working, data record doesn't show up on admin page

Comment: did you try it in `shell` ? it i should save an instance. Add your admin code in the question and notify me in the comments